# Dynamic speech bubble in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, popover

I'm trying to make something like this:
[image: CSS speech bubble]

I'd like to use pure CSS. Bootstrap v3 is already loaded.

I've gotten pretty close with something like

```
.bubble {
                   position:relative;
                   left: 15px;
                   padding: 10px;
                   background: #FFFFCC;
                   margin: 5px 5px;
                   max-width: 250px;
                   border: #FFCC00 solid 1px;
                }

.bubble:before {
                   position:absolute;
                   content: ""; 
                   top:15px;left:-10px;
                   border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0px;
                   border-color: transparent  #FFFFCC;
                   border-style: solid;
                 }
```

But the result is not quite what I'm looking for.

I've searched around and fiddled a bit, but have not found an elegant solution that fits my needs.

Years ago I would have done this with tables and images, but surely there's a better way in 2015?

Comment: Searching on codepen, there seems to be a lot of examples, some you may just need to modify so they expand as more content is added:
http://codepen.io/skoupidia12000/pen/gkriF     http://codepen.io/palimadra/pen/nlIDj  / This one: http://codepen.io/bvdr/pen/DnoKI only needs width changed to "auto" and it will stretch to fit content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a 2015 version...

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFFFCC;
    border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
    max-width:250px;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:arial;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    border-radius:6px;

}
.bubble:after,
.bubble:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.bubble:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 204, 0);
    border-right-color: #FFFFCC;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.bubble:before {
    border-color: rgba(255, 204, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #FFCC00;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

**SEE IT IN ACTION:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ajahb5p1/

**NOTE:**

You can adjust the size of the arrow simply by changing the `border-width` and `margin-top` values in the `.bubble:after` definition (currently set to 15px and -15px)

To make sure it retains it's border, you would also need to change these same 2 values in the `.bubble:before` definition (currently set to 16px and -16px)

Comment: No worries, if this helped you, please accept the answer. Thx